# Simple residential blower control

Tags: timer

[image]Basic question is: Is it permissable / safe to connect a $10 plug in timer relay with potential for backfeed from a second source?  20 watt fan being switched.  This is a SIMPLE question, compared to those I see here. Hope you won't laugh too hard!
[image]

Comment: What happens if the plug is inserted backwards?

Comment: Most, if not all, plug in timer relays already have a switch to allow the timer function to be bypassed and the device to be continuously powered.  Thus an external switch is not required.

Comment: Timer can only work in the bottom outlet so it does not cover top half.  SO no problem. thanks for input.

Comment: This one cannot be bypassed, see photo just dropped in

Comment: Not likely to insert backwards since the timer labelling is read right side up and would be unreadable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If the timer relay you're talking about is a customer level product made to be plugged into the wall, I would trust it for a 20W fan. But, if you're making your own thing, I would use a Triac or Thyristor instead of a relay. The difference is thyristors are make to only turn off when their current is around 0, so you do not need to worry about inductive backlash. On the down side, this gives you less control of timing.

Comment: Yep, just a simple off the shelf home depot timer-- $10. OK, solved my problem.  Just wanted to be sure!